# Duplicate detection on client side not working in CRM 2016

Tags: popup, duplicates, dynamics-crm, detection

I'm working with CRM 2016 on prem. I have 2 customs entites, let's call them custA and custB. CustA has a 1:N relationship with custB. So when adding existing custB's to custA in CRM 2011, if I was creating a duplicate (adding a record that I'd already added) I got a popup telling me I'm trying to create a duplicate. In CRM 2016 I don't get this pop at all. It won't allow me to create the duplicate, but I don't get the popup. Any idea's if this is something that can be fixed via configuration or is client side notification removed in CRM 2016 altogether?

Answer (score 1):

This was moved to the [Alternate Keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dn932139.aspx) feature. See how to create keys via customizations [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/29e53691-0b18-4fde-a1d0-7490aa227898.aspx)

You can use that to check duplicate records and also even from the SDK, which is handy when you need to Integrate data from external systems too.